# SQL Server Remote Query TCP Error

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking, sql-server, tcp, ssms

We are in the process of moving to a new hosting provider and after setting up a very simple database in SQL Server 2005, I noticed that if I wait more than 10 seconds or so between running queries remotely using management studio, I get the following error:

> A transport-level error has occurred
>   when sending the request to the
>   server. provider: TCP Provider, error:
>   0

We also get a similar error when running an SSIS package from our office to the hosted database.

The host has not been very helpful at all, so I'm trying to narrow down what the problem could possibly be. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at the firewalls between you and them. Most firewalls have an idle session timeout setting of some kind to keep idle sessions (connected but no data flowing) from consuming resources (RAM, CPU, session state table entries, etc). See if your host is aware of what this setting is on their firewall and see if it's an adjustable setting.

Comment: It was the firewall. After I finally convinced them that the problem was on their side, they found a sql session timeout setting in the firewall, which was set to 10 seconds.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.